add_route_to_plc fails in pyads under Linux
I want to connect to my Beckhoff PLC, CX5110, running TwinCAT 3.1, build 4024.62 via ADS protocol under Linux. While trying to add_route_to_plc an error occurred in the pyads lib:

Error-Message:
Connected to pydev debugger (build 242.23339.11)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vrees/.local/share/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2024.2/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1570, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/vrees/.local/share/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2024.2/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/vrees/work/git-repos/heatpump2influxdb/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    pyads.add_route_to_plc(CLIENT_NETID, CLIENT_IP, PLC_IP, PLC_USERNAME, PLC_PASSWORD,route_name=ROUTE_NAME)
  File "/home/vrees/work/git-repos/heatpump2influxdb/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyads/ads.py", line 200, in add_route_to_plc
    return adsAddRouteToPLC(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/vrees/work/git-repos/heatpump2influxdb/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyads/pyads_ex.py", line 169, in wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/vrees/work/git-repos/heatpump2influxdb/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyads/pyads_ex.py", line 375, in adsAddRouteToPLC
    raise RuntimeError(f"Unexpected response from PLC: {data!r}")
RuntimeError: Unexpected response from PLC: b"\x03f\x14q\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x80\x05|\xca\xe0\x01\x01\x10'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x04\x00\x04\x07\x00\x00"
python-BaseException


The debug output shows, that the PLC answers with reasonable data. But the check if the received password is correct fails as the expected data does not match the true or false condition. It looks like that the parsed data is somehow shifted by one byte.

Has someone experienced similar issues?
